# Query Results Differ From SSRS Results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a query that pulls accurate data when ran on SSMS, but when I create a report using SSRS with the exact same query, it misses out results that come from one of two temp tables I use.

```
DECLARE @from int --= @fromparameter
DECLARE @to int --= @toparameter

/*
For debug
*/
set @from = 0
set @to = 50
/*
================================================================================
Build a temp table with all accounts that have a move out date within params
================================================================================
*/

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tempProperty', 'U') is not null drop table #tempProperty
select 
    sa.spark_AccountNumber
    ,sa.spark_PropertyIdName
into
    #tempProperty
from
    SparkCRM_MSCRM.dbo.spark_account sa
where
    sa.spark_AccountNumber IN (
                                select distinct
                                    sa.spark_AccountNumber
                                    --,sa.spark_TenantMoveinDate
                                    --,sa.CreatedOn
                                    --,DATEDIFF(day,sa.spark_TenantMoveinDate,sa.CreatedOn) as [Difference]
                                from
                                    SparkCRM_MSCRM.dbo.spark_account sa
                                where
                                    sa.spark_TenantMoveinDate BETWEEN dateadd(DAY,@from,getdate()) AND dateadd(DAY,@to,getdate())
                                )


/*
================================================================================                                                           
--create CTE with all accounts per property
================================================================================
*/
--;with RowRanked (AccountNumber,Name,Rowrank,MoveinDate,MoveOotDate,SProperty,PProperty)

--AS                                                                                                                                           
--( 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp', 'U') is not null drop table #temp                                                                                                                                     
    SELECT                                                                                                                                 
         sa.spark_AccountNumber [Account Number]                                                                                                           
        ,sa.spark_name [Account Name]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sa.spark_PropertyIDName ORDER BY COALESCE (sa.spark_TenantMoveinDate, sa.spark_agreementdate) DESC) [rowRank]
        ,COALESCE (sa.spark_TenantMoveinDate, sa.spark_agreementdate) [Tenant Move In Date]
        ,sa.spark_TenantMoveoutDate [Tenant Move Out Date] 
        ,sa.spark_PropertyIdName [Property ID]
        ,p.spark_name [Property Name]
    into #temp
    FROM
        SparkCRM_MSCRM.dbo.spark_property p
    LEFT JOIN
        SparkCRM_MSCRM.dbo.spark_account sa
        on sa.spark_PropertyId = p.spark_propertyId
    WHERE
        sa.spark_PropertyIdName IN (SELECT spark_PropertyIdName from #tempProperty)
--)

/*
================================================================================
build final dataset
================================================================================
*/
select distinct
    sa.spark_AccountNumber                      [Account Number]
    ,sa.spark_name                              [Name]
    ,concat (
            sa.spark_HouseNumber ,' ',
            sa.spark_HouseName  ,' ',   
            sa.spark_Address1   ,' ',   
            sa.spark_Address2   ,' ',   
            sa.spark_Address3   ,' ',   
            sa.spark_Address4   ,' ',   
            sa.spark_Postcode
            )                                   [Address]
    ,sa.spark_Email                             [Email]         
    ,sa.spark_HomePhone                         [Landline]
    ,sa.spark_Mobile                            [Mobile Number]
    ,COALESCE(a3.Name,a2.Name,a1.Name)          [Letting Agent Partner]
    ,sa.spark_tariffidName                      [Tariff]
    ,sa.spark_PPMTariffName                     [PPM Tariff]
    ,pm.Option_Label                            [Payment Method]
    ,sa.spark_Balance                           [Account Balance]
    ,sa.spark_IntendedMoveOut                   [Date of Likely Move Out]
    ,sa.spark_TenantMoveoutDate                 [Current Tenant Move Out Date]
    ,rr.[Account Number]                        [New Account Number]
    ,rr.[Tenant Move In Date]                   [New Account Move In Date]

    ,case
        when pc.spark_CallDriver is not null 
            then 'Yes'
        else
            'No'
    end                                         [Arrangement to Pay]
    ,ds.Option_Label                            [Stops]

from
    SparkCRM_MSCRM.dbo.spark_account sa
--inner join
--  DBS.dbo.Meter m    
--  on m.cust_ref = sa.spark_AccountNumber collate DATABASE_default
--  and m.meter_status = 2
left join 
    SparkCRM_MSCRM.dbo.spark_property sp
    on sp.spark_propertyid = sa.spark_propertyid

left join 
    SparkCRM_MSCRM.dbo.account a1                --branch
    on sp.spark_PartnerId = a1.accountid

left join 
    SparkCRM_MSCRM.dbo.account a2                --brand
    on a1.parentaccountid = a2.accountid

left join 
    SparkCRM_MSCRM.dbo.account a3                --partner
    on a2.parentaccountid = a3.accountid

left join       
    SparkCRM_Custom.dbo.GetCRMOptions('spark_account', 'spark_paymentmethod') pm 
    ON pm.Option_Value = sa.spark_paymentmethod
left join
    SparkCRM_Custom.dbo.GetCRMOptions('spark_account','spark_DebtorStatus') ds
    on ds.Option_Value = sa.spark_DebtorStatus
left join
    SparkCRM_MSCRM.dbo.PhoneCall pc
    on pc.spark_Account = sa.spark_accountId
    and pc.spark_CallDriver = 101
left join
    #temp rr
    on rr.[Property ID] = sa.spark_PropertyIdName
    and rr.Rowrank = 1

where
    coalesce(
        sa.spark_IntendedMoveOut
        ,sa.spark_TenantMoveoutDate
        ) 
    BETWEEN 
        dateadd(DAY,@from,getdate()) AND dateadd(DAY,@to,getdate())

and
    sa.spark_name not like '%occupier%'
```

This returns data when I run the query in SQL Server Management Studio, but copying it into SSRS Report Builder seems to remove any results from the #temp table. You'll notice that I was originally use a CTE for the second table, but I tried using a temp table instead in case it SSRS was struggling with CTEs.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using SQL Profiler to capture the query SSRS is actually executing?

Comment: I haven't tried that, that's really helpful thank you. I'll give it a go and see where it leads me. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using #temp tables in Reporting Services, if for no other reason that it will cause all sorts of trouble if people try to run the report concurrently.

It would be better for you to instead create a Stored Procedure that your Report can call.  This will allow you to apply indexes and another performance modifications as needed, and it will behave exactly the same as running the query stand-alone in SSMS

Comment: That's excellent, thanks Jonnus.

As it happens, the report is now returning the same data as when ran in SSMS, despite no changes to the query or report file. 

I've often wondered what the benefits of embedding a query vs calling a SPROC was; thank you for your advice.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to upvote, but I have accepted the answer! Thanks again.

Comment: Report Builder will also cache its results until changes are made to the dataset, so it will not always match SSMS even on normal queries.